# Colspan align Twitter Bootstrap on window resize?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am new to using Twitter Bootstrap and I can't wrap my head around their idea of grid organization. Basically I want to arrange this page with the right set of information colspaning the left. I tried nesting the information with rows, and just kept nesting until I got lost. In the example with JSfiddle below, the table looks fine when the window is wide enough but when you shorten the width of the window the pieces stack out of order. Right 1-6 should stack together (if they must stack at all). Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/wBg8Y/

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default col-lg-12">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src='../../../images/mpIcon.PNG' class='sm-icon' />
        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>-->
       Menubar
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>-->
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <!--<div class="jumbotron col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">-->
  <div class="jumbotron col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          left top   
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">right 1</div>
       <div class="col-md-3">right 2</div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">Markets</div>

            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 3</div>

            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 4</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 5</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 6</div>



      </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">right 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">right 4</div>

        <div class="col-md-3">right 5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">right 6</div>

    </div> <!-- /row -->        
  </div> <!-- /jumbotron -->  

  <div class="col-md-6">Copyright 2013 Deloitte Development LLC</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <a href='#'>About</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Contact</a> |
    <a href='#'>FAQ</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Help</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Support</a>

  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was over thinking it. Solved. Wrapping the left section in  helped segregate it from the right.

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default col-lg-12">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src='../../../images/mpIcon.PNG' class='sm-icon' />
        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>-->
       Menubar
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>-->
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <!--<div class="jumbotron col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">-->
  <div class="jumbotron col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          left top   
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">right 1</div>
       <div class="col-md-3">right 2</div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">Markets</div>

            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 3</div>

            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 4</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 5</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 6</div>



      </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">right 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">right 4</div>

        <div class="col-md-3">right 5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">right 6</div>

    </div> <!-- /row -->        
  </div> <!-- /jumbotron -->  

  <div class="col-md-6">Copyright 2013 Deloitte Development LLC</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <a href='#'>About</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Contact</a> |
    <a href='#'>FAQ</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Help</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Support</a>

  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working:

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default col-lg-12">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src='../../../images/mpIcon.PNG' class='sm-icon' />
        <!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>-->
       Menubar
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div><!--<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>-->
        </form>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <!--<div class="jumbotron col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">-->
  <div class="jumbotron col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
          left top   
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-3">right 1</div>
       <div class="col-md-3">right 2</div>

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12">Markets</div>

            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 3</div>

            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 4</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 5</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">markets left 6</div>



      </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">right 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">right 4</div>

        <div class="col-md-3">right 5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">right 6</div>

    </div> <!-- /row -->        
  </div> <!-- /jumbotron -->  

  <div class="col-md-6">Copyright 2013 Deloitte Development LLC</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <a href='#'>About</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Contact</a> |
    <a href='#'>FAQ</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Help</a> | 
    <a href='#'>Support</a>

  </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: You've copied a large block of this code from a previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35561926/189134). Please don't simply copy and paste your posts between questions. Instead, make sure to answer the question being asked.